# no redirection of default controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

It works fine on the localhost. But when i upload my files on a webhost it doesn't redirect to a default controller. However by entering the url manually it loads the pages. what must we consider for loading the default controller?

here's my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# Set the rewritebase to your CI installation folder
RewriteBase /


# Send everything to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I've set the baseurl in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$config['index_page'] = 'index';
```

here's my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Home"; // Home is my default controller
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: Actually, `index` in `$config['index_page']` should be [index.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L38).

Comment: Thanks tpojka but it didn't work.

Comment: It works fine by entering URL manually for eg. www.webpage.com/index.php/Home. But when I enter www.webpage.com. it doesn't redirect to Home controller

Comment: Does `Home.php` (pay attention on capital H in file/class name) controller has an `index()` method within?

Comment: <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

 
 public function index()
 {
  $this->load->view('Home');
 }
 
 
}

Comment: What is exact error shown?

Comment: Directory access is forbidden.

Comment: Check `FCPATH` directory (one where `index.php` file persists) and make sure it has CHMOD of 755.

Comment: Also, your all publicly accessible files such are css, js and images files have to be in FCPATH or some kind of subdirectory of it (I.E. assets). Then, you would put something like `base_url('assets/css/style.css')` or `base_url('assets/js/main.js')`. If those files (css/js/etc) are in `views` directory website won't work.

Comment: Dont do this: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> Fnd out from your hoster if mod_rewrite is supported or not. and have them review your htaccess file at the same time to make sure its the correct format for their server environment.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your following code in config.php

From:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index';
```

To:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```